# How to get jackson to hide the field data if the user is not authenticated?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a `product` class with 2 fields `name` and `price` and I want to only send the `price` only if the user is authenticated.

Is there any jackson annotation that allows me to do this?

Comment: `if (!isUserAuthenticated) { price = null; }` and also tell jackson to not show `null` values on the json output. Also you may be able to use [JsonView](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)

Comment: yeh the only way I manage to made it reusable was JsonView with AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice